# will disabling javascript in browser affect ajax calls and js functions

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have a doubt

i guess there are some options like disabling javascript in the browser.

if so then ajax and javascript functions wont work isnt it? if so is there any solution? .

Answer (score 3):

**YES** disabling JS will disable JS... so no AJAX as it's done with JS...

only solutions are server-sided fallbacks.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is what is called **progressive enhancement**:

- Make your site work without Javascript, then
- Add the fancy ajaxy layer on top.

That way, users without Javascript will still get a functional site.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX = Asynchronous **JavaScript** and XML, so of course ajax and javascript functions won't work. Javascript has to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax and jQuery are Javascript, so yes, they're disabled also.although you didn't ask for jQuery but still.

Something to learn about [Graceful Degradation](http://webtips.dan.info/graceful.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: no, they won't work.

And there is no particular solution, only thing you can do is use `<noscript>` tag and notify the user about his browser settings.